# Import data via Importxml only from a specific team

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, google-sheets-formula

This site delivers the data as follows:

[image]

I managed to import the two columns I need but it imports from all teams:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(1,{1;IMPORTXML(A2,A3)},(ROW($A$1:$A400)+1)*2-TRANSPOSE(sort(ROW($A$1:$A$2)+0,1,0)))))
```

[image]

Actually I wish that in cell `A1` I could write the team name like for example: `Aston Villa`. And the import would only pull the names and expected returns from the players of that particular team. Like for example:

[image]

This extra detail when filtering importxml I could not create, I would like help with that. I leave here the link of the spreadsheet used as an example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1krZm-V1geMkz4PeD35GBhiMHdG5kMHnEx-g0iG6oxes/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(A2,"table", VLOOKUP(A1, {
 IMPORTXML(A2, "//h3[@class='injuries-title']"), ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
 IMPORTXML(A2, "//h3[@class='injuries-title']"))))}, 2, 0)), 
 "select Col2,Col4 offset 1", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to help me in one detail. Some players have information in the ```INFO column``` called ```Away on International duty```. These players I wish they didn't appear on the list. Could you help me filter out this detail? I left an example of a team that has players with this data. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A0CICP4VcuG6EaJLm7aErCYqoGRSs5RX097McEHVC8M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(A2,"table", VLOOKUP(A1, {
 IMPORTXML(A2, "//h3[@class='injuries-title']"), ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
 IMPORTXML(A2, "//h3[@class='injuries-title']"))))}, 2, 0)), 
 "select Col2,Col4 where not Col3 = 'Away on International duty' offset 1", 0))`

Comment: Thanks player0, Perfect!